# Why does point move after executing this function from keybinding

Tags: org-mode, save-excursion

I have the following line in my `init.el`:

```
(define-key
  org-mode-map 
  (kbd "C-c C-p") 
  (lambda () (interactive) (org-publish-project "publish-website"))
  )
```

The `"publish-website"` argument points to an element of my `org-publish-project-alist`.  This works as expected, except that it moves my point to the start of the buffer when I execute it (which is very annoying).  I have two questions (thanks in advance for your help):

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, but `org-publish` probably is. However, you can fix the problem by using `save-excursion`:

```
(define-key
  org-mode-map
  (kbd "C-c C-p")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (save-excursion
      (org-publish-project "publish-website"))))
```

`save-excursion` is a macro that saves the point and the current buffer, runs the code you provided, then restores point and the current buffer to the saved values.

Comment: `save-excursion` is exactly what I needed; elisp has so many nice built-in functions I don't know about :)

Comment: There are certainly quite a lot of them. There are a few other `save-foo` macros you might go look up as well.